# How to animate width/height changes due to content changes?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations

In the example below, when you click the button some content is added to the div. I want to animate the div getting bigger. Is this possible with pure CSS?

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#content').append("<p>Ab atque aut cumque dolor exercitationem officia, perferendis quis vel. Autem deserunt ea maiores quaerat quos temporibus! Aperiam dolorem dolores, eaque ex ipsam laborum minima nesciunt nulla porro quaerat vel?</p>");
});
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: yellow;
  
  transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab cupiditate debitis dolores dolorum ea, eligendi ex, expedita illum incidunt ipsum itaque neque optio quisquam quo vel veniam voluptatem voluptatibus, voluptatum.</p>

</div>

<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a mask wrapper to the #content and apply the css transition to it and with Javascript change it's height. You need to get the new height from the #content everytime you append new content (height changes).

```js
var $contentMask = $('#contentMask');
var contentBoxId = '#content';
var currentHeight = getCurrentHeight(contentBoxId);
$contentMask.css('height', currentHeight);

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $(contentBoxId).append("<p>Ab atque aut cumque dolor exercitationem officia, perferendis quis vel. Autem deserunt ea maiores quaerat quos temporibus! Aperiam dolorem dolores, eaque ex ipsam laborum minima nesciunt nulla porro quaerat vel?</p>");
  currentHeight = getCurrentHeight(contentBoxId);
  $contentMask.css('height', currentHeight);
});

function getCurrentHeight(selector) {
 return $(selector).height();
}
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#contentMask {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentMask">
  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab cupiditate debitis dolores dolorum ea, eligendi ex, expedita illum incidunt ipsum itaque neque optio quisquam quo vel veniam voluptatem voluptatibus, voluptatum.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

You can see it also in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iamgutz/fsagbLn9/

Comment: Was really hoping I wouldn't have add anything to the 'click' handler. The DOM changes are actually handled by React -- that's gonna be really hard, if not impossible to hook into... or maybe not, I do have a `render()` method. Will have to experiment with this. Thanks

Comment: I got this working, but only in certain contexts where the state propagates from above this component. Kind of hard to explain. Looks neat though when it works :-) Thanks for the help